# Python datetime strptime() and strftime(): how to preserve the timezone information

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, python-dateutil

See the following code:

```
import datetime
import pytz

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'

d = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
d_string = d.strftime(fmt)
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_string, fmt)
print d_string 
print d2.strftime(fmt)
```

the output is

```
2013-02-07 17:42:31 EST
2013-02-07 17:42:31
```

The timezone information simply got lost in the translation.

If I switch '%Z' to '%z', I get

```
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
```

I know I can use `python-dateutil`, but I just found it bizzare that I can't achieve this simple feature in datetime and have to introduce more dependency?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that the strings usually used to represent timezones are not actually unique. "EST" only means "America/New_York" to people in North America. This is a limitation in the C time API, and the Python solution is… to add full tz features in some future version any day now, if anyone is willing to write the PEP.

You *can* format and parse a timezone as an offset, but that loses daylight savings/summer time information (e.g., you can't distinguish "America/Phoenix" from "America/Los_Angeles" in the summer). You can format a timezone as a 3-letter abbreviation, but you can't parse it back from that.

If you want something that's fuzzy and ambiguous but usually what you want, you need a third-party library like `dateutil`.

If you want something that's actually unambiguous, just append the actual tz name to the local datetime string yourself, and split it back off on the other end:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
dtz_string = d.strftime(fmt) + ' ' + "America/New_York"

d_string, tz_string = dtz_string.rsplit(' ', 1)
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_string, fmt)
tz2 = pytz.timezone(tz_string)

print dtz_string 
print d2.strftime(fmt) + ' ' + tz_string
```

Or… halfway between those two, you're already using the `pytz` library, which can parse (according to some arbitrary but well-defined disambiguation rules) formats like "EST". So, if you really want to, you can leave the `%Z` in on the formatting side, then pull it off and parse it with `pytz.timezone()` before passing the rest to `strptime`.

Comment: I think that replacing `EST` by `America/New_York` is not a good idea: they are elements from different sets. `America/New_York` belongs to the set containing among others `Europe/Rome` and `Africa/Dakar`, while `EST` has as siblings `EDT`, `CET`, `UTC` as well as `EST` and `CEST`. Moreover, whether `Europe/Rome` means `CET` (UTC+1) or `CEST` (UTC+2) depends on the calendar day and on political choices, which may vary per year. I would follow @Johnny's answer.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, `strptime()` can only handle the timezone configured by your OS, and then only as a time offset, really. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime):

> Support for the `%Z` directive is based on the values contained in `tzname` and whether `daylight` is true. Because of this, it is platform-specific except for recognizing UTC and GMT which are always known (and are considered to be non-daylight savings timezones).

`strftime()` doesn't officially support `%z`.

You are stuck with `python-dateutil` to support timezone parsing, I am afraid.

Comment: Actually, `%z` _is_ supported, on most POSIX systems, under the "Additional directives may be supported on certain platforms" rule (one paragraph from the end of your link). See `http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#id2`at the bottom of the page, too. But it's not _documented_ to work on any particular system (in practice, it only works if your platform is POSIX and the native libc function supports it), and it's also not documented what happens if you use it on a system that can't handle it, and usually that's as bad as "doesn't work".

Comment: Right; altered to 'officially' then. The support in the stdlib for timezones is lacking tremendously. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I believe the proposal to add full tz features in some future version any day now is alive yet again. This time, the idea of just including tzdb with Python for Windows and other platforms that don't have it natively isn't being immediately laughed out of court because "making Python 131KB bigger" isn't very scary anymore. But there is the whole issue of keeping the database up to date…

Comment: I always imagined that that last point is the reason why there is no good TZ support in the stdlib…

Comment: Well, IIRC, the reason there was no support in 1.6 or 2.0 or whenever this was first suggested was actually more about about the 131KB… and the fact that some platform (SGI?) did come with zoneinfo but it was broken. But yeah, now that we're past those two problems, the idea that on Windows, 3.4.0 and 2.7.4 (or whatever) will be frozen at the 2013 definitions forever is pretty scary, considering how many people are still using 2.7.2, or even 2.6.x, today…

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer in Python 2.7

#### Print current time with timezone

```
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal  # pip install tzlocal

print datetime.now(tzlocal.get_localzone()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

#### Print current time with specific timezone

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # pip install pytz

print datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

It will print something like

```
2017-08-10 20:46:24 +0800
```

Comment: The meat of the question is `strptime()`. Also, totally misses the point about the lack of global standard timezone names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pytz
import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'

d = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
d_string = d.strftime(fmt)
d2 = pytz.timezone('America/New_York').localize(d.strptime(d_string,fmt), is_dst=None)
print(d_string)
print(d2.strftime(fmt))
```