# Convert odd timestamp with offset to UNIX time in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I have a timestamp string from a web log that looks like this:

> 10/Jun/2005:05:59:05 -0500

It like to convert it to a UNIX timestamp.

A `datetime` can be converted with `time.mktime(datetime.timetuple())`

According to the [`datetime` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), `datetime.strptime()` should convert it to a datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("10/Jun/2005:05:59:05 -0500","%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z")
```

At least on with Python 2.7.2 on my Mac, this results in

> ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'

After reading many questions on SO about that error, I decided to try `python-dateutil`:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("10/Jun/2005:05:59:05 -0500")
```

That didn't work either:

> ValueError: unknown string format

Now what?

Comment: `%z` is not supported by `strptime()`; see [Python datetime strptime() and strftime(): how to preserve the timezone information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14763274)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dateutils`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) to make the converstion, you will need two steps:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> d = parse('10/Jun/2005:05:59:05 -0500', fuzzy=True)
```

This will create a datetime object

```
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2005, 6, 10, 5, 59, 5, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

And to convert it to UNIX timestamp:

```
>>> ts = calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple())
>>> print ts
1118401145
```

Comment: Oh, that magical `fuzzy`.