# Python: Get aware datetime string from aware datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have an aware datetime-object and want to return an aware datetime-string. However when I do

```
obj.strftime("%e %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

it returns a UTC-based string (even though `TIME_ZONE`-setting is set right).

How can I get a localised datetime-string?

EDIT: I want the timezone of django to get applied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python datetime strptime() and strftime(): how to preserve the timezone information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762518/python-datetime-strptime-and-strftime-how-to-preserve-the-timezone-informat)

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateformat.py i think OP expect a solution using the django defined timezone

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `localtime(obj)`:

```
localtime(obj).strftime("%e %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module dateformat inside your project, it allows to get the timezone from your settings :

```
from django.utils import dateformat

timezoned_date = dateformat.DateFormat(obj).format('jS F Y H:i:s')
```

EDIT :

This works fine with unaware `datetime` objects, better use `django.utils.timezone.localtime` with aware dates.

Comment: still giving UTC instead of the declared timezone back

Comment: how did you test it ? i tried this by generating a datetime.now() and the ouptut was fine according to different timzones.