# What is the difference between strptime and strftime?

Tags: python

I am working on a project , where  I have dictionary with column date called "starttime" .. I need to extract month , hour and year , day of the week.
I am stuck for now I have the below code .

```
   {if city =='NYC':
        datn = datum[('starttime')]
        datn = dt.strptime(datn,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
        hour = dt.strftime(datn,"%H")
        year = dt.strftime(datn,"%y")
    elif city == 'Chicago':
    datc = datum[('starttime')]
    datc = dt.strptime(datc,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
    month = dt.strftime(datc,"%m")
    hour = dt.strftime(datc,"%H")
    year = dt.strftime(datc,"%y")
    else:
    datw = datum[('start date')]
    datw = dt.strftime (datw,"%m")
    hour = dt.strftime(datw,"%H")
    year = dt.strftime(datw,"%y")
                              
return (month, hour, day_of_week)
   }
```

my import statements are on the top of my code , as below:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

strptime translates to

```
"parse (convert) string to datetime object."
```

strftime translates to

```
"create formatted string for given time/date/datetime object according to specified format."
```

Why do you need strftime?

> This is what a datetime object looks like: (2015, 7, 19, 22, 7, 44,
>   377000)
>
> To someone who isn't quite familiar with this format, with the
>   exception of the year, what's written up there is not immediately
>   intuitive. So you probably would be better off with something like
>   Sun, 19 July, 2015. That's what strftime is used for. You simply need
>   to learn the proper formatting strings.

One  [Good Link over SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762518/python-datetime-strptime-and-strftime-how-to-preserve-the-timezone-informat)  read about this !

Answer (score 1):

strptime converts the string to a datetime object.

strftime creates a formatted string for given time/date/datetime object according to specified format by the user

you would use strftime to convert a datetime object like this: datetime (2018, 10, 20, 10, 9, 22, 120401) to a more readable format like "20-10-2018" or 20th of October 2018.